# Linux command to copy file contents one word per line into a new file created from the same command

Tags: linux, shell

I need to copy the file contents one word per line into a new file created from the same command.

This is the file:

```
Never
gonna
give you up
Never
gonna
let you down
Never
gonna
turn around and desert you
```

Command already tried:

```
cat a6q4-input.txt >> a6q4-pt2.txt
```

This copies the file to newly created file a6q4-pt2.txt in exact format however does not changes the layout of the word content to one word per line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tr` to replace spaces with newlines:

```sh
tr ' ' '\n' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I'll try working with tr as well, let me update you.

Answer (score 1):

Perl one-liner:

```sh
perl -lne 'print for split' a6q4-input.txt > a6q4-pt2.txt
```

For each line of the files given on the command line (`-n`), split it up into words based on whitespace with `split`, and print each one on its own line with `print`. `-l` adds a newline after each print (And strips them from each line when read).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options):

```
cat in_file | xargs -n1 > out_file
```

Or use a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lane 'print for @F' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)